# Xcopy certain file names only

Tags: windows, xcopy

I've never used the Xcopy feature before and I was wondering if it would be possible to use xcopy to copy only certain files within a directory tree.

For example, suppose I have the following documents: 
\servername\generateddocuments\2014\20141231\GUID1.doc
\servername\generateddocuments\2014\20141231\GUID2.doc
\servername\generateddocuments\2015\20150101\GUID3.doc
\servername\generateddocuments\2015\20150101\GUID4.doc

Now, suppose I have a spreadsheet that tells me which .doc files I need to copy: 
GUID1.doc
GUID3.doc

Is there a way to base the xcopy on the spreadsheet(or txt document) so I don't copy the files I don't need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think xcopy can read files to *include* from a file. But you can create a batch file that does this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (documents.txt) do (
   copy %%A x:\targetfolder\
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your solution would do? Sorry, I am unfamiliar with xcopy and I don't quite understand what you've referenced.  ~newer than a newbie here.  :)

Comment: This is a set up for a batch script that can read a text file (like your list of documents) line by line. Each line is read into the variable %%a and for each of them a command (in this case 'copy') is executed. This is my suggested workaround for the fact that xcopy doesn't have the possibility to read the list of documents itself.

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol! Your solution worked! I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Try typing HELP XCOPY at a command prompt and look at the /EXCLUDE parameter. The documentation isn't quite correct, you can put a list of files in a single file, one file name per line, and they will be excluded from the xcopy.